# Eslint configuration for jsx props spacing, inline and multiline

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, config, typescript-eslint

I want a certain eslint rule that auto format on every save (I already enabled the extension and its setting). The rule condition is:

Example there's a react component with 6 props. If I write those props inline, the rule should make sure there's space between those props.

Meanwhile if the length of the written inline props exceed the max-len OR if I press enter and moved one of the props to new line, the rule should be able to automatically moved the rest of the props to new line as well (so one line for each props). Also the rule should auto delete empty lines between prop.

Please anyone have any idea to apply this Eslint rules in Typescript Nextjs project?

Big Thanks.

```
extends: ['airbnb-base', 'airbnb-typescript/base', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'next', 'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended', 'plugin:import/typescript',
    'next/core-web-vitals', 'plugin:eslint-comments/recommended',
    'plugin:promise/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'promise', 'eslint-comments',
    'import'],
  rules: {
    {...other rules}
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': [2, { max: 2, maxEOF: 0 }],
    'react/jsx-props-no-multi-spaces': ['error'],
  },
```

Heres my eslintrc.js config. I have this rule added

```
'react/jsx-props-no-multi-spaces': ['error']
```

So far it fixed the space between props problem, but not the multiline props problem.